# Global mysqlpool for node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am currently working on a Node.js project with Express and [Mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). I want to create a global mysql connection pool. Whenever I need to access the DB, i just `require` the js file that has access to the db pool. Here is how I am currently doing this.

```js
module.exports.mysqlPool = (function(){
 var mysqlconfig = require(__dirname + '/config/mysql.config.js');
 mysqlconfig.connectionLimit = 10;
 return mysql.createPool(mysqlconfig);
})();
```

My question is: **If i include this file in multiple parts of project, is it going to run every time and waste resources by creating multiple connection pools?** I don't want it to create a new pool every time i require the file. I want it to only run once. Is this a good approach to this problem, or is there a better way?

Thanks for your input.